# Writings about Nusach Provence

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, nuschaot

Last Thursday, I had the honour of looking at a handwritten machzor (Rosh haShannah) from somewhere in Provence. I noticed that it is completely different from almost anything I've seen, bearing the greatest similarity to Nusach Italia.

Are there any books, ideally in English or French, which discuss the nusach of the Provençal kehillot?

Comment: Check out Nusach Appam

Comment: @DoubleAA, something I'd love to do, but from what I know from Wikipedia, Nusach Appa"m is based on Nusach Tzarfat, which is more Ashkenazi in flavour (see the Machzor Vitry et al., who were Tzarfati Rishonim)

Comment: I may have been mixing up Avignon and Asti. The point is there are a couple cities in France or Italy that still do these things. They weren't expelled from France because they were owned by Venice or Papal states or something like that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Asti is in Italy, known for his false Champagne, Avignon is mamash in Provence. The Chidda in His masaot told about the various Bate Knesset in Avigno, but at his epoque there was no provencal nussach

Comment: The Meiri in Shut Magen Avot argued for the ancestral nussach of Provence and against the widespread of the Ramban views,  a celebre shut is about kel melech neeman before shema Israel. http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/8902

Comment: @kouty, how is Asti wine anything like Champagne? Having had both, I can't note any similarity, other than the fact that they're both «gaseux»

Comment: when I was younger Asti Spumante was regarded as an as if of Champagne

Comment: See this link about nusach tsarfat,  which may help you   https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/נוסח_צרפת

Comment: and this    https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/נוסח_פרובאנס

Comment: http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2012-11-09_Tefila_Newsletter_Supplement.pdf